# Change part of background-image: url with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I had to shift the image resources of my website to under a new domain. So all the image links are broken. For the images however, I have changed the `src` with jQuery using the following function below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');;
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('www.old', 'images.new'));
    });
});
```

But it works for the `<img src="">` links only. I have some other images as the background of different `div` where this function doesn't work. Such as:

```
<div class="hero" style="background-image: url('https://www.old.com/image.jpg');"></div>
```

How can I change the part of this `background-image: url('https://www.old` to `background-image: url('https://images.new` with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target all the elements with the style `background-image` and includes the old path and replace their `background-image` src using [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');;
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace('www.old', 'images.new'));
  });

  $('[style*="www.old.com"]').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', function(i, old) {
      return old.replace('www.old', 'images.new')
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/kuceqes/edit?html,js,console